# Power supply design - what safety mechanisms are needed?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, safety

When evaluating or designing a power supply for instrumentation (let's say a CT scanner b/c that's my field, and the environment is always changing), what safety mechanisms should I verify?

What I can think of is

- Transient input suppression
- Load short circuit handling
- Component thermal limits
- Arcing / voltage tracking between traces

I'm considering a switched mode buck supply, possibly isolated.

What are other considerations to ensure the supply doesn't damage other components, it doesn't smoke, and that no one gets electrocuted?

Is there a standard that, if I follow, the design is considered safe?

Personally, I find this field quite different from civil engineering, where there are lists of mandated calculations you must do for a particular project.

Comment: "Personally, I find this field quite different from civil engineering, where there are lists of mandated calculations you must do for a particular project." UL and other certifying organizations generally require an applicant to perform a battery of tests. The number of required tests may vary depending upon how much of your solution is "novel", i.e. not already certified. I don't know what kind of certification is generally used for medical equipment, but you might want to consult with them on how to minimize the burden of testing.

Comment: If you're designing medical equipment you shouldn't be brainstorming random ideas on the internet, you should be reading and following the standards.

Comment: If it's powering something expensive, over-voltage protection on the output(s) could be useful.

Comment: As others have said, you need to be much more concerned about the safety of the patient than you seem to be. You must consider all of the possible ways that your equipment could malfunction such that the equipment itself would be safe but the patient would be endangered. You must also demonstrate that your equipment does not interfere with any other equipment. This is serious business, and you should not expect to get authoritative answers here.

Comment: Patient safety isn't a concern if it is inside the body.  Yes, leakage current is tested on the entire system.  I only chose a CT scanner because, if you represented the scanner as a finite state machine, it is always changing,. Motors are being fed various currents, readout electronics can draw like 70W when the beam is on, EMI inside the machine is probably high.

Answer (score 1):

It might differ outside of Europe, but the following could be used as some basic overview of how to evaluate and select the standards needed, before comercializing a power supply.
Before starting with the design process you should define the following:

- Customer / Field (e.g. medical, industrial, etc)
- Location to be used (e.g. country)
- Standards

Depending where and who you final customer is, the requirements and respective tests might change.

As an example, let's say you are designing a medical-graded open-frame 40W power supply, to be comercialized in Europe.

Until recently the IEC/EN 60950 (devices in the field of information and communication technology and for devices in the audio/video sector) was the basic standard that most of the electronics devices had to comply with before going to market. However, it was replaced in 2020 with the new IEC/EN 62368 standard. In some cases, for example industrial power supplies, you could even use the IEC/EN 61010 instead.

I am not familiar with medical-graded devices, but since it is the case it should also comply with the standard IEC/EN 60601 (Medical Electrical Equipment).

In order to ensure that your device is neither affecting or being affected by electromagnetic disturbances, it should also fulfill the requirements given by the standard IEC/EN 61000.

In summary:

- EN 62368 (Basic Safety Requirements)
- EN 60601 (Medical Safety Requirements)
- EN 61000 (Electromagnetic Compatibility)

As for the tests, you should read the applicable sections of each standard and define a test plan accordingly. Next step would be to discuss with a standard expert, and a certification body since they will be the one conducting the final test on your power supply.

As you can see the standard and test selection can get quite complex, and that's why there are experts in this field, who also make sure that all the currently certified devices are still valid and up-to-date with the standards. Here are some additional design requirements / tests for your list:

- Minimum creepage / clerance
- Minimum hold-up cycles (AC)
- Maximum allowed energy stored in the capacitors
- Ratio of volume to capacitance
- Exposed energized pins
- Mechanical / Electronic Interlocking
- Maximum stored energy
- Overload / short-circuit protection etc ...

Although not 100% guaranteed, you can have a look at the certifications of some similar off-the-shelf power supplies. For example, this [medical-graded power supply](https://www.tracopower.com/sites/default/files/products/datasheets/tpp65a_datasheet.pdf) complies exactly with the standards mentioned above in adition to EN 55011. This should give you a good indication whether you are well covered.

This is a basic example and should not be taken as any sort of final solution. The best thing to do, is to consult a standard expert and a certification body, who will inform your exactly what you need.